# How to properly call the fields in this query?

Tags: query

Addtional_Contact_Role__c has a lookup field to Contact. Why doesn't this Query work (what needs changing)? And can you explain why it is wrong? Where in eclipse can one see the correct relationship naming?

```
select ID,Email,(SELECT name from Additional_Contact_Role__r) FROM Contact
```

Comment: the relationship name usually be in plural... try Additional_Contact_Roles__r

Comment: The plural name is Positions (apparently the object was renamed). It didn't work.

Comment: Did you tried with Plural Name which is there in Object Field Level?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b go to `Addtional_Contact_Role__c` and go to contact lookup field and find relationship field name and append __r and then try. And if this is managed package part then just add  namespace too.

Answer (score 1):

If Addtional_Contact_Role__c has a lookup field to Contact, it means that Contact object is parent obj, Addtional_Contact_Role__c is child obj.

> select ID,Email,(SELECT name from Additional_Contact_Role__r) FROM Contact

This query is calls child from mother obj. It supposed to be parent from child.

> select Contact__r.Id, Contact__r.Email, Name from Additional_Contact_Role__r

Please check the link for more details about object relationships https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the lookup to contact is on contact_role it may be easier to query the other way around.

```
SELECT ID,Name,Contact__r.Email FROM Additional_Contact_Role__c
```

Comment: I get this error : Didn't understand relationship 'Additional_Contact_Role__r' in field path.

Comment: Hi Nielsm, This Query won't work because the Additional_Contact_Role has the Lookup to Contact and he is querying the Contact Object. So he wants to access the child records from parent

Comment: I updated my response. Maybe more usefull if you tell some more about your use case. What do you need, what information do you have for filtering the query?